# access specific properties file at runtime in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, bean-validation, properties-file

I have a spring boot app and I'm trying to internationalize the bean validation errors. So I have added the locale specific properties file containing the validation messages and used a localresolver to change the locale .The validations are the locale change is working fine. The issue is that with the validation message Im also appending the field name for eg : "payer.toAddress.legalName" . For the better user experience I need to fetch a the translation for this fieldname from the correct properties file.
How do I implement the code to read the value for the key "payer.toAddress.legalName" from the ValidatioMessages_XX.properties ? XX stand for the current language code set in the validator.

```
 ConstraintViolation<ValidCustomer> constraintValidation = constraintViolations.stream().findFirst().get();

      String invalidField = constraintValidation.getPropertyPath().toString();
      String errorMsg = String.format("%s - %s", invalidField, constraintValidation.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file will be read only once, when the application starts up. There isn't any functionality with spring that allows to automatically read  a properties file dynamically on runtime.

In that case if you want to dynamically read it you could either move that property in database where your application accesses on runtime or you natively read some file but you need to write the code for it.

If you want to read it only once, when the application starts up then the following code will inject you the value that you expect to use.

Use `@Value` annotation to inject the value inside a spring bean

```
@Component <--- must be a component or anything else that spring registers as a bean
public class YourClass {

   @Value("${payer.toAddress.legalName}")
   String legalName;

 }
```

Comment: Seems like db table is the only way to go. The issue is that I need to take the value for payer.toAddress.legalName from the file matching the current language code of the user. And this is only resolved once the request is received at api. Thanks for the help :)